# Как определить, человек заходит на страницу по адресной строке или переходит на нее с сайта?

Tags: javascript

Есть мультистраничник. При заходе через адресную строку включается прелоадер. Но сайт имеет несколько страниц и при клике на логотип с другой странице, человека перенаправляет на главной где снова включается прелоадер. Но суть в том что если пользователь заходит на главную через клик по логотипу от других страница, не надо что бы включался прелоадер. Вообщем как в js сделать такое условие, что бы определить , человек перешел с с внутренней страницы либо зашел как в первый раз через адресную строку

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это можно определить при помощи [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer#Syntax) и [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Syntax).

Вам нужно проверить содержит ли `document.referrer` в себе `window.location.origin`. В случае, если пользователь зашел на сайт по URL, то `referrer` будет пуст. В противном случае он содержит ссылку на страницу, с которой пользователь перешел на текущую. Выглядит примерно так:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.origin) != -1) {
    console.log("from our site");
}
else {
    console.log("from external site");
}
```